# JAVAFX FXML Scene not staying within layout constraints or screen resolution

Tags: javafx, controls, fxml, screen-resolution

This is a short two part question: 1. I have designed all the UI for my database in Javafx scene builder 2.0 on a scene size 1920 x 1080; however, I need it to resize based on the screen resolution of the system its operating on. How can this be done?. 2. Second problem which goes hand in hand with the first is all of the controls I have placed in the scene are not staying within the size or location constraints I set. When I preview the scene from the tool everything is correct, but when I run the program everything is out of whack. Any suggestions on what I can do to correct these issues without a complete redesign?

the FXML code:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeView?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.InnerShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65"xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MAAT.MainScreenController">
  <children>
  <Pane layoutY="-5.0" />
  <TabPane fx:id="mainpane" layoutY="35.0" maxHeight="1047.0" maxWidth="1920.0" prefHeight="1047.0" prefWidth="1920.0" side="LEFT" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
    <tabs>
      <Tab fx:id="AHTAtab" text="All Hazard Threat Assessment">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="1009.0" prefWidth="1871.0">
                 <children>
                    <TableView fx:id="AHTATable" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="56.0" prefHeight="928.0" prefWidth="1840.0">
                      <columns>
                        <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="132.0" sortable="false" text="Classification" />
                        <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="95.0" text="T/H/C" />
                          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="364.0" sortable="false" text="Category &amp; Capability" />
                          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="1122.0" sortable="false" text="Rating Definition" />
                          <TableColumn prefWidth="137.0" text="Rating Score" />
                      </columns>
                       <effect>
                          <InnerShadow />
                       </effect>

                          </TableView>
                    <Button fx:id="AHTAedit" layoutX="1718.0" layoutY="994.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit" />
                    <Button fx:id="AHTAdel" layoutX="1785.0" layoutY="994.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                    <AnchorPane layoutX="22.0" layoutY="11.0">
                       <children>
                          <Button fx:id="Tbtn" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Threat" />
                       </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                    <AnchorPane layoutX="107.0" layoutY="11.0">
                       <children>
                          <Button fx:id="Hbtn" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Hazard" />
                       </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                    <AnchorPane layoutX="199.0" layoutY="11.0">
                       <children>
                          <Button fx:id="Cbtn" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Cyber" />
                       </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab fx:id="AAtab" text="Asset Analysis">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                 <children>
                    <TreeView fx:id="AAlist" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="105.0" prefHeight="845.0" prefWidth="583.0">
                       <effect>
                          <InnerShadow />
                       </effect>
                    </TreeView>
                    <Label layoutX="16.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="88.0" text="Asset List: " underline="true" wrapText="true" />
                    <Button fx:id="Addassetbtn" layoutX="387.0" layoutY="966.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Assets" />
                    <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="38.0" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="587.0" text="Upon selecting the  &quot;Add Asset&quot;  button and completing the form each asset and its related dependencies will appear below." wrapText="true" />
                    <Button fx:id="AARemovebtn" layoutX="509.0" layoutY="966.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Remove" />
                    <AnchorPane layoutX="644.0" layoutY="105.0" prefHeight="845.0" prefWidth="1203.0" visible="false">
                       <children>
                          <ListView fx:id="Hpairlist" layoutY="645.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1203.0">
                             <effect>
                                <InnerShadow />
                             </effect>
                          </ListView>
                          <ListView fx:id="Tpairlist" layoutY="402.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1203.0">
                             <effect>
                                <InnerShadow />
                             </effect>
                          </ListView>
                          <Label layoutY="375.0" text="Paired Threats:" />
                          <Label layoutY="618.0" text="Paired Hazards:" />
                          <Separator layoutY="360.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="1202.0" />
                          <Label fx:id="AAclassification" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="466.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="270.0" text="Classification placeholder" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="817.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="466.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="467.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0" />
                          <Label layoutY="70.0" text="Asset Name:" />
                          <Label layoutX="502.0" layoutY="70.0" text="Unclassified Asset Name:" />
                          <Label layoutX="999.0" layoutY="70.0" text="Criticality Score:" />
                          <Label layoutY="111.0" text="Mission:" />
                          <Label layoutX="1.0" layoutY="225.0" text="Impact Statement:" />
                          <TextArea fx:id="Amission" editable="false" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="138.0" prefHeight="87.0" prefWidth="1202.0" wrapText="true">

                          </TextArea>
                          <TextArea fx:id="Aimpact" layoutY="252.0" prefHeight="99.0" prefWidth="1202.0" />
                          <Label fx:id="Aname" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="393.0" />
                          <Label fx:id="UAname" layoutX="707.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="283.0" />
                          <Label fx:id="Crit" layoutX="1132.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="65.0" />
                       </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                    <Separator layoutX="621.0" layoutY="105.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="846.0" prefWidth="6.0" />
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </Tab>
        <Tab fx:id="RATtab" text="Risk Analysis Tool">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                 <children>
                    <TableView fx:id="RATtable" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="83.0" prefHeight="902.0" prefWidth="1842.0">
                      <columns>
                        <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="216.0" text="Threat/Hazard" />
                        <TableColumn editable="false" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="313.0" text="Critical Asset" />
                          <TableColumn editable="false" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="480.0" sortable="false" text="Observation" />
                          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="120.0" sortable="false" text="Vul. " />
                          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="135.0" text="Int. Risk " />
                          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="370.0" sortable="false" text="Recommendation" />
                          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="112.0" sortable="false" text="R. Vul" />
                          <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="93.0" text="R. Risk" />
                      </columns>
                       <effect>
                          <InnerShadow />
                       </effect>
                    </TableView>
                    <Button fx:id="Obbtn" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="37.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Observation" />
                    <Button fx:id="RATed" layoutX="1713.0" layoutY="994.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit" />
                    <Button fx:id="RATdel" layoutX="1780.0" layoutY="994.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                    <Button fx:id="CRbtn" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="37.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cumulative Risk" />
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </Tab>
    </tabs>
  </TabPane>
  <MenuBar fx:id="MMBar" layoutX="-6.0" layoutY="-5.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="1927.0">
    <menus>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New">
                 <accelerator>
                    <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="N" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                 </accelerator>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open" />
              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save">
                 <accelerator>
                    <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="S" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                 </accelerator>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As...">
                 <accelerator>
                    <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="S" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                 </accelerator>
              </MenuItem>
              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Import" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Export" />
              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close Window">
                 <accelerator>
                    <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="W" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                 </accelerator>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit">
                 <accelerator>
                    <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="Q" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                 </accelerator>
              </MenuItem>
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
  </children>
  </Pane>
```

Comment: Suggestions for 2. without redesign? None. My suggestion would be "a complete redesign" going through those nodes you use the fact that your nodes are inside a `AnchorPane` for none but one `Node`. For all other nodes the parent node could be a `Pane` too. Also in general you shouldn't (over)use absolute positioning. In this case you most likely would change ALL those positions/sizes depending on the screen resolution.

Comment: I've gone through and recreated the screen, yet I am still having issues with buttons not maintaining their spacing within the pane.